# flutter Mapping error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' in type cast

Tags: flutter

I use `bottomNavigationBar` with two items which I define in a map:

```
final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
{
  'page': CategoriesScreen(),//My categories widget
  'title': 'Categories',//title of current page (with navigation bar)
},
{
  'page': FavoritesScreen(),//My favorites widget
  'title': 'Your Favorite',//title of current page (with navigation bar)
},
```

];

When I use it like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title']),
  ),
  body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],//<----- ERROR HERE
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(....
```

When I try to run the app from Android studio I got the error:

**type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' in type cast**

Any Idea why?

*Update 1 (full code)*:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    
import './favorites_screen.dart';
import './categories_screen.dart';

class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsScreenState createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {

  final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
    {
      'page': CategoriesScreen(),
      'title': 'Categories',
    },
    {
      'page': FavoritesScreen(),
      'title': 'Your Favorite',
    },
  ];
  
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title']),
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        // type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.category),
            title: Text('Categories'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.star),
            title: Text('Favorites'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: How does that even compile in the first place? Please post an [mcve]. Your `Map<String, Object>` should be an actual class with typed members, not some dynamic map where with some luck you get the right type maybe.

Comment: That is not actually a [mcve]. Also, if I make it into an [mcve], it works, so it's probably in the parts you were missing. So please do your debugging homework and create a [mcve]. You might find out where your error comes from in the progress and if not, you can post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put it into a Map. Just use the List<Widget> for _pages and add the title the State widget of the TabsScreen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    
import './favorites_screen.dart';
import './categories_screen.dart';

class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsScreenState createState() => _TabsScreenState();
 }

 class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {

  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    CategoriesScreen(),
    FavoritesScreen(),
  ];

  String title = 'Categories';

  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
      if (_selectedPageIndex == 0) {
          title = 'Categories';
      } else if (_selectedPageIndex == 1) {
          title = 'Your Favorite';
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        // type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.category),
            title: Text('Categories'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.star),
            title: Text('Favorites'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm still looking for a more elegant way of achieving but this approach works.

Answer (score 0):

following your code this is what you should do instead

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './categories_screen.dart';
import './favourite_screen.dart';

class TabsScreeen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsScreeenState createState() => _TabsScreeenState();
}

class _TabsScreeenState extends State<TabsScreeen> {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
    {
      "page": CategoriesScreen(),
      "title": "Categories",
    },
    {
      "page": FavouriteScreen(),
      "title": "Favourites",
    }
  ];

  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title']),
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black38,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        onTap: _selectPage,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.category,
            ),
            label: 'Categories',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
            ),
            label: 'Favourites',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Instead of typing:`final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages`
do:  `final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _pages`
So replace Object with dynamic type.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and it was solved like this:

1- Keep your final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages as it's.

2- Add "As String" to the Text: title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title'] as String),

3- Add "as Widget" to the body: body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,

The full code:

```
class _TabsState extends State<Tabs> {

  final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
    {'page': Categories(), 'title': "Categories"},
    {'page': Favorites(), 'title': "Your Favorites"},
  ];

  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title'] as String),<-- Add this
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget, <-- Add this
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
          onTap: _selectPage,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.category),
              label: 'Catogries',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.star),
              label: 'Favorites',
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your list mapping, change object to dynamic(your value can take any form)
like...
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _pages